# Capybara and chrome driver: SQLite3::BusyException: database is locked

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, sqlite

Once in a while I use chromedriver when running my feature specs to do some visual testing etc. For this, I simply set `driver: :chrome` on the specific spec.

I didn't do this for a long time it seems, as since I tried it today, I got the following error:

```
SQLite3::BusyException: database is locked
```

This doesn't happen when running the specs using the default JavaScript driver (which is poltergeist).

A search on Google lead to this [solution which shows how to monkey patch active record](http://atlwendy.ghost.io/capybara-database-locked/). Still, this feels odd to me. Why did it work before? Is it some threading issue? I don't like monkey patching, maybe there's a better solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-rails/blob/master/features/choose_javascript_database_strategy.feature) feature in cucumber-rails:

> When running a scenario with the @javascript tag, Capybara will fire
>   up a web server in the same process in a separate thread to your
>   cukes. By default, this means ActiveRecord will give it a separate
>   database connection, which in turn means data you put into your
>   database from Cucumber step definitions (e.g. using FactoryGirl) won't
>   be visible to the web server until the database transaction is
>   committed.
>
> So if you use a transaction strategy for cleaning up your database at
>   the end of a scenario, it won't work for javascript scenarios by
>   default.
>
> There are two ways around this. One is to switch to a truncation
>   strategy for javascript scenarios. This is slower, but more reliable.
>
> The alternative is to patch ActiveRecord to share a single database
>   connection between threads. This means you still get the speed
>   benefits of using a transaction to roll back your database, but you
>   run the risk of the two threads stomping on one another as they talk
>   to the database.
>
> Right now, the default behavior is to use truncation, but you can
>   override this by telling cucumber-rails which strategy to use for
>   javascript scenarios.
>
> The deletion strategy can be quicker for situations where truncation
>   causes locks which has been reported by some Oracle users.

From the last paragraph, you could use the deletion strategy by changing the following line in `env.rb`:

```
Cucumber::Rails::Database.javascript_strategy = :truncation
```

by:

```
Cucumber::Rails::Database.javascript_strategy = :deletion
```